# Iterate through count of resources with terraform templatefile & save individual file per iteration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

**Iterate through count of resources with terraform templatefile & save individual file per iteration.**

Hi, I am trying to move from using `template_file` to using `templatefile` in terraform.

Terraform needs to loop through a count of nodes, then create a individual file for each node.

I use count inside my terraform `data` and `resource` for `template_file` but this does not work in `locals`. As count is only used in resources. I believe I need to use a for loop but not quite sure how to implement it.

Here are examples of the `template_file` method. These work perfectly but I would like to convert them to use `templatefile`

```
    #Template Data
    data "template_file" "ansible_inventory" {
      count    = var.node-count
      template = "${file("./inventory.tpl")}"
      vars = {
        host_ip  = element(aws_eip.node_eip.*.public_ip, count.index)
        vpc_name = var.vpc_name
      }
    }
    
    #Template Write
    resource "null_resource" "inventory" {
      count = var.node-count
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "echo \"${element(data.template_file.ansible_inventory.*.rendered, count.index)}\" > /tmp/${var.vpc_name}_node_${count.index}.ini"
      }
      depends_on = [data.template_file.ansible_inventory]
    }
```

And here are the contents of the `inventory.tpl` that is used:

```
    [all]
    ${host_ip} StrictHostKeyChecking=no -F /tmp/${vpc_name}_node.cfg'
```

---

I would like to use `locals` to accomplish this and save an individual files per "`var.node-count`". How do you approach this via `templatefile`?
What do I need to change in the `inventory.tpl` file? Any help is appreciated.

```
    locals {
      #count = var.node-count #### count does not work
      ansible_inventory = templatefile("${path.module}/inventory.tpl",
      {
        host_ip  = element(aws_eip.node_eip.*.public_ip, count.index)
        vpc_name = var.vpc_name
      })
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the `ncount` template variable? I don't see it being used anywhere in the file itself.

Comment: whoops, you are right. it was unused. I removed it.

Comment: You could use `count`, `local_file` (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) and `templatefile` to populate the `content` argument the same way you had it defined previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible to achieve with the combination of `count`, `local_file`  [1] and `templatefile` built-in function. This should be enough to create what you need:

```
resource "local_file" "inventory" {
    count    = var.node-count
    content  = templatefile("${path.module}/inventory.tpl", {
        host_ip  = element(aws_eip.node_eip.*.public_ip, count.index)
        vpc_name = var.vpc_name
    })
    filename = "/tmp/${var.vpc_name}_node_${count.index}.ini"
}
```

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file

Comment: Yeah, the number of lines is much lower than before. Always happy to help!